# Device Owner app does not set as owner app after installed from QR code provisioning on Samsung Tab

Tags: android, kotlin, emm, android-device-owner

I have created device owner app for my organization. It will be used within company. I have follow all [steps](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#example_qr_code_bundle) and successfully generate QA and checksum. Also able to install it form QA code. Now i am able to set my app admin by launching intent for setting but it's still not owner app. After restart tab its just start like normal start. I have set my app as HOME and DEFAULT but still not launcing. My Manifiest file is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_PASSWORD_COMPLEXITY"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
        tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.setupwizard.SETUP_COMPAT_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.GRTKioskLauncher">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:lockTaskMode="if_whitelisted"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.CHECK_POLICY_COMPLIANCE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ADMIN_POLICY_COMPLIANCE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.GET_PROVISIONING_MODE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyDeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_conf" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
```